# Re-write output on different images on Views Slideshow

Tags: 7, media, javascript, views

Using this - [tutorial](http://www.webomelette.com/views-rewrite-results-drupal-7)

I have a views slideshow that rotates images with a fade effect.
I know you can re-write output to show images and a text field below but so far I can just add one text block - I want each image to have its own text!

Answer (score 0):

### [Image Field Caption](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_field_caption)

> Adds an extra text area for captions on image fields.
>
> Similar to the alt and title text fields available with an image
> field, the caption text area can be used to enter text or html
> descriptions of an image.

Has views integration.

Comment: I have done it but no caption option appears in the 'replacement tokens' part of rewrite results - I have cleared the cache! [http://i.imgur.com/G4xtSal.png]

Comment: I haven't used this module myself, but maybe the caption is a field on its own. So when you're adding fields search for caption.